# How Can I add a letter to a "data" animated number counter? (Wordpress - TheFox Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, numbers

At the top of this page: http://550.9f2.myftpupload.com/about/

I've inserted an `animated` number counter, which was included in my wordpress theme, the problem is that I need it to count to **"52K"**, but if any non-number characters are inserted it shows up as **"NaN"**. Does anyone know of a trick I can use to make this work? Preferably with **CSS**.

I've tried using the `:after` pseudo element selector to insert **"K"** as content, using the below:

```
.number_k:after {
  content: "K";
  color: #000;
  font-size: 62px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  top: -29px;
  left: 150px !important;
}
```

But as the screen size is **adjusted**, the **"k"** jumps around the screen, how can I get it to stay **attached directly** to the right of the number counter?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add text behind or before your counter with a single pseudo:

```css
p {
  counter-reset:bs;
}
b{
  counter-increment:bs;
}
b:before {
  content:counter(bs)'K '
}
```

```html
<p><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm afraid I don't fully understand though. I tried altering my css to the below

.number_k:after {
    content: counter(bs)'K';
    color: #000;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: relative;
    top: -29px;
    left: 150px !important;
}

Comment: I understand a bit more now, I've changed it to simply: 

.count_number:after {
  content:counter(bs) 'K'
}

But it's inserting a 0 before the K, do you know why that is?

Comment: GOT IT! Thank you! Turns out I had the right idea, but I was accidentally applying the pseudo content to the Div AROUND the numbers, not the counting numbers themselves.